# Rotate only one screen

Tags: xrandr

If I have only the internal monitor (`LVDS1`) with an `xrandr -o left` command. Now I want to attach a second monitor, say to `HDMI1`. Then I'd like to rotate only the internal monitor, but not the external one. I tried the following (with no external attached though, since I am mobile currently), but that does not do anything:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 -o left
```

How can I rotate only one monitor?

I do need some command line, since I want to put this into a script.

Comment: are you using an nvidia graphics card?

Comment: No, I use the Intel Card in the i5.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The trick is to use the newer `--rotate` instead of `-o` which needs to be used with a `--output` argument:

```
xrandr --output "$internal" --rotate "$xrandr_rotation"
```

#### Examples

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --rotate left
xrandr --output LVDS1 --rotate right
xrandr --output LVDS1 --rotate normal
xrandr --output LVDS1 --rotate inverted
```

Comment: and you can string these together for `--` like so: `xrandr --output VGA1 --auto --output HDMI2 --auto --right-of VGA1` or for `|-` like so: `xrandr --output VGA1 --auto --pos 0x0 --rotate left --output HDMI2 --auto --pos 1200x300`

Comment: You can use `xrandr --query` to find the name of the display adapter output that your monitor is plugged into (the above example, the monitor is plugged into `LVDS1`).

Comment: You are a savior! Whey the manpage still says `-o` is beyond me! Here we are, seven years later ...

Comment: when i do this command, which works it leaves a large black bar running across my background image, as if the background image is no longer properly aligned with the screen. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you open the `System Settings` and choose `Displays` there, you can select the monitor to rotate, and choose which rotation to use, for each individual monitor you wish to rotate.

Comment: This is nice, but not scriptable. So I need something which I can invoke from the command line.