# Change only one display orientation from terminal

Tags: display, xrandr, system-settings

I am starting to work with 2 displays on Ubuntu. One of them is rotateable, so I can use it easily in both landscape and portrait mode. But I world prefer to have ability to change orientation setting (which could be found in System Settings->Desktop) from terminal or script on one display but don't rotate other one.

I am pretty sure it is possible via `xrandr`!

Comment: Is your question mainly on how to *script* it, or how to do it with xrandr? In the last case, you will find it here: http://askubuntu.com/a/171154/72216, but it can be made changeable / toggle with a key combination of course, but then the scripting is actually the question.

Comment: @JacobVlijm as I just found answer on my own from `man`. Thanks. I think that `bash` script with `xrandr` command inside will work, won't it?

Comment: Absolutely. The nicest would be to toggle; make a script read from xrandr what is the current rotation of the second screen, set it to "the other option" under a shortcut key.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I did it, using basicly `xrandr` and `grep`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Strange, but I found answer first!

You use

```
$ xrandr --output $monitorName --rotate $direction
```

where `$monitorName` can be found in output of

```
$ xrandr
```

and `$direction` is `left` for counter-clockwise or `right` for clockwise.

**Edit**: Using `grep`, it is possible to write a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

screen="HDMI1"

descr=$(xrandr | grep "$screen")
if echo "$descr" | grep disconnected
then
        echo "No $screen connected"
        exit 1
fi

alt="left"
if echo "$descr" | grep --quiet -P "^[^(]*$alt"
then
        rotate="normal"
else
        rotate="$alt"
fi
xrandr --output $screen --rotate $rotate
```

which actually switches orientation of monitor storaged in `$screen` variable, and `$alt` is the alternative orientation.

Comment: nice, and it works!

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to use `xrandr` for that.

```
xrandr -o $orientation
```

Where `$orientation` is `left`, `right`, `inverted`, or `normal`.

You can select the display you want to rotate with the `--display` option.

Comment: `--dsplay` selects X server, not the monitor, does it?