# Scaling does not work separately for different monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-resolution, 20.10

I have two monitors (internal and external), external one has a much higher resolution compared to my internal one.

If I don't scale, because of the resolution difference, the bigger screen does not work properly (text is unbearably small or distorted), but if I do scale, it's scaling the built-in monitor as well.

I have a Windows machine and I noticed in Windows 10 it (almost) automatically adjusts the bigger screen to 150% scale while keeping the original one at 100%.

What do I need to do to make it work on Ubuntu? I prefer to work on Ubuntu and I'm gradually transitioning over to Ubuntu unless it is something I have to be using Windows.

Is there any way I can fix this issue or is there any way I can give feedback to the Ubuntu team (hoping that one day they'll fix this issue)?

External display settings:

[image: External display settings]

Internal display settings:

[image: Internal display settings]

I followed [one of the comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084069/how-to-set-different-scaling-on-multi-monitor-3-monitors) below and was be able to do what was recommended, however when I fixed the 4K external monitor my internal 1920x1080 monitor's scale went up as well.

Two things:

1. The scale value under settings did NOT change, it's still 100%, but the actual visual scale is different.
2. Since there is only one HDMI port on my laptop, I used a USB to HMDI convertor (honestly I suspect that may be the reason, but I don't have enough knowledge to verify it).

I even tried to download and install LightDM display manager, SDDM, and made sure I have GDM as well.

I am using Ubuntu 20.10, waiting for 21.04 to become available.

Comment: Check this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084069/how-to-set-different-scaling-on-multi-monitor-3-monitors. Not sure if that will properly work.

Comment: @vanadium: Thank you for your prompt reply!! that seems very similar to my situation. Really appreciated!