# Why is my screen upside down when booting into ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot

I am running a HP laptop with W-7 and Ubuntu. In windows the screen is fine and does'nt change in any way. When I boot into ubuntu 18.04, the screen is upside down but the cursor is correct.
I tried the alt-up arrow and the screen turns back BUT the cursor is then upside down, just the inverse of the display. It doesn't seem to be a display setting but something with Ubuntu.
This has been a problem since I installed Ubuntu. I've been trying for literally weeks to get this fixed.
Is there a patch or a permanent fix for this problem? 
Since everything is displayed wonky I need very precise instructions. 
It is very difficult to navigate the display in Ubuntu as it is. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upside down mouse cursor and inverted position on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061403/upside-down-mouse-cursor-and-inverted-position-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 1):

found something on your problem, I'm copying [a response from the problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061403/ubuntu-18-04-1-upside-down-mouse-cursor-and-inverted-position), these are not my words and i have no wish to claim them

You can just run:

```
sudo apt remove iio-sensor-proxy
```

and reboot then. Everything would come back to normal.

or

I tried following instructions:- Click Here for instructions, but that didn't work. Then what I did was simply inverting the screen using the `xrandr --output eDP-1 --rotated inverted` and opening up Terminal using <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+T</kbd> shortcut and simply performing a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. After rebooting, everything went back to normal. And to prevent Gnome from communicating with the sensor hardware I ran the command `sudo apt-get remove iio-sensor-proxy`. This solved everything for me.

Comment: Thank you. I did find that the problem has something to do with the Nvidia drivers. Not sure what to do about it though.